# React navigation getting params only once

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

I'm using react nativation and I'm trying to pass a param to a screen. However, when I do it, it only works the first time, and when I try to access the same screen using different values, the navigation works but the screen keeps the values from the very first navigation event. For example, when I select the user `John Bolton`, it displays the information of said user. However, when I go back and select another user, it always displays the info of `John Bolton`.

This is the code where I access the screen:

```
goToUserPanel = item => {
  const { navigation } = this.props;

  const selectedUser = item;

  navigation.navigate('UserPanel', { selectedUser });
}
```

And this is the screen where I recieve the params:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    const { navigation, properties } = props;
    const selectedUser = navigation.getParam('selectedUser', null);

    this.state = {
      allProperties: properties.allProperties || [],
      selectedUser: selectedUser,

      selectedUserImage: selectedUser.userImage,
      selectedUserName: selectedUser.userName,
      selectedUserId: selectedUser.id,
      selectedUserVerified: selectedUser.verified,

      propertiesFiltered: [],
      modalVisible: false
    };
 }
```

I don't think it is a stackNavigation issue, since as I told earlier, the parameter passing works, but ONLY the very first time, then subsequent times it keeps the data from the very first time. Still, if you're curious, here's the code of the stackNavigator

```
const ProfileDrawer = createDrawerNavigator(
  {
    Profile: UserProfile,
    About: AboutScreen,
    UserProfileEdit: EditUserProfile,
    EditUsers: EditUsers,
    UserPanel: UserPanelScreen,
    ListProperties: PropertiesList
  },
  {
    drawerWidth: WIDTH * 0.69,
    drawerType: 'front',
    drawerPosition: 'right',
    contentComponent: UserProfileDrawer
  }
);
```

Comment: I think the problem is you are setting up the parameter `selectedUser` in the constructor. That code only gets run once.

Comment: That's a valid comment, however, I have another pair of screens that have almost the same behaivour and those have no problems of this type

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked the value of 'item' and 'selectedUser' before this line to verify if they contain the desired value? This may give you some hint about the issue.

```
navigation.navigate('UserPanel', { selectedUser });
```

Comment: Yes, I did a ```console.log(item);``` and a ```console.log(selectedItem);``` before the navigation. It always returns the values of the user that I'm trying to display the info on the ```userPanel``` screen, but the ```UserPanel``` screen still "keeps" the values of the first ever navigation event.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
const screen1 = (props) => {
    goToUserPanel = item => {
        const { navigation } = this.props;
        navigation.navigate('UserPanel', { 
            selectedUser: item
        });
    }
}

const UserPanel = (props) => {
    let selectedUser = props.route.params.selectedUser;
    console.log("Selected User", selectedUser);
}
```